# which event should my listview handle to do an action when any item is selected in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

i need help to desactivate a button when there are any item select in my listview.
here is my code :

```
Private Sub ListView_ItemSelectionChanged(____) Handles ListView.ItemSelectionChanged
    If ListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        btnDelete.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

i need to know which event shoul my procedure handle to make my program work correctly.

Comment: I'm not experienced using `ListView`, but this seems the correct event to me. Any problem with your current approach?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you want `Enabled` to be `True` when items are selected, not `False`.  The other problem I see with your code is that it's not disabling the `Button` again if no item is selected.  Do this instead:

```
btnDelete.Enabled = (ListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
```

I'd also try a descriptive name for your `ListView`.